# Failed to create Release artifact directory error after cancelling Release and starting new one

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This seems to only happen if I cancel a release deployment and then start a new one. It forces me to go into the agents and manually restart them.

The actual error is..

"Failed to create Release artifact directory 'C:\agent_work\r3\a'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\?\C:\agent_work\r3\a' because it is being used by another process."

Is there a way in TFS to clean up any of these potential issues when creating a new release after a cancelled one? If I let it fully run its course, the new release runs fine no problem. This only happens when I cancel and attempt to start a new one.

Comment: What are the tasks in your release pipeline? It looks like the some process started by release pipeline task is not closed properly and still using Release artifact directory when you cancel the release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use utility like [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to write a script that releases locked files or folders.

For example:

```
$pathToRelease = $env:System.DefaultWorkingDirectory
Write-Host "$PathToRelease is locked! trying to kill the process..."
$processes = path\to\handle64.exe -nobanner -accepteula $PathToRelease

# Remove empty lines
$processes = $processes | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""}
Write-Host $processes.ForEach({ Write-Host $_ })

if($processes -notmatch "No matching handles found.")
{
   foreach($process in $processes)
   {
       # Some excluded processes, you can decide what which you want
       if($process -match "explorer.exe" -or $process -match "powershell.exe"
       {
                continue
       }
       $pidNumber = $process.Substring(($process.IndexOf("pid") + 5),6)
       $isProcessStillAlive = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.id -eq $pidNumber}
       if($Null -ne $isProcessStillAlive)
       {
           Stop-Process -Id $pidNumber -Force
           Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
       }
   }
}
else
{
   exit 0
}
```

Configure the script to run even the release is canceled.